# All dates in Antd Datepicker are selected when value is passed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, components, antd

When using the DatePicker component from Ant Design and setting its value with the `value` prop, all dates in the pop-up calendar are highlighted in blue as if they are selected.

Moving the cursor over the pop-up calendar causes the date and month to change automatically without any click.

Clicking the "back" button also causes the year to change.

This issue does not occur when the DatePicker is not a controlled component. ( value is not passed as a prop )

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vmn72j-yyrkz4?file=demo.tsx)

Ant-Design Version: `5.1.2`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Change from moment js to dayjs

Ant Design is using `Dayjs` as a date library from `5.0.0`.

Till `4.x` it is `momentjs`.

The issue is because of passing a moment object as value to datepicker which expects a dayjs object internally.

We need to pass dayjs object instead of moment js object to resolve the issue.

Check this [LIVE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vmn72j-uzegdx?file=demo.tsx)

If you want to use moment as your Date Library for your project follow [this guide](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-custom-date-library)

Answer (score 0):

We had the exact same issue but with antd vue `v1.7.8`. The solution was to add the `badMutable` dayjs plugin. In antd some of the code use something like `month.date(1)`. In momentjs the date is mutable, but not in dayjs. If you are using `antd-dayjs-webpack-plugin` you can configure it like this:

```js
const AntdDayjsWebpackPlugin = require('antd-dayjs-webpack-plugin');
config.plugins.push(new AntdDayjsWebpackPlugin({
  replaceMoment: true,
  plugins: [
    'badMutable', // add this
    'isSameOrBefore',
    'isSameOrAfter',
    'advancedFormat',
    'customParseFormat',
    'weekday',
    'weekYear',
    'weekOfYear',
    'isMoment',
    'localeData',
    'localizedFormat',
   ]
}))
```